# Document Library Crawl

Tags: sharepoint, search, web-crawler

I set up a new scope and passed in the URL for a specific document libary that I created that hold 2 word documents.

For some reason when I start a full crawl, it does not see the 2 word documents.

The word documents have meta data and I've created Managed Properties that map the crawled properties.

I am trying to utilize the Advanced Search webpart to be able to search from this scope. When I enter a search term such as the filename of the word document, no results are returned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the document library to be searchable. Enable it through the document libraries properties.

### Edit

See [Harnessing Properties in SharePoint Search](https://web.archive.org/web/20070831010632/http://www.intranetjournal.com/articles/200508/ij_08_29_05a.html)

To get to the Document Library Advanced Settings page, from within a given library, select the Document Library Settings menu item from the Settings dropdown, and then select the Advanced settings hyperlink under the General Settings header. Somewhere in there, you should see something like the following image. Make sure that the radio button is set to Yes. [Source](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint_blank/archive/2008/10/21/sharepoint-document-library-advanced-settings.aspx)

[image]
<sub>(source: [bamboosolutions.com](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/bambooteamblog/Search.jpg))</sub>

Comment: this is only for SP 2003

not SP2007

Comment: Oh. Sorry I assumed you were on 2007 since your question didn't specify 2003.

Comment: By default lists are included in search results

Answer (score 1):

What account is the crawler running as?  Maybe that account doesn't have read permission on the list, so it can't index it.

Can you find information from the same documents in other document libraries, when using the default search scope?

Can you find information from this document library using the default search scope?

Are you trying to create a custom search results page, or just scope?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is to check the search crawl log to see if there were any errors when it was searching the library.